# Cannot GET /api/auth/register

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make a new API REST with NodeJS, Express, and MongoDB.
I can't go to my path. The web browser is sending: `Cannot GET /api/auth/register`.

I have already checked if I have some POST request but I don't. I really don't understand right now what's going on. All other routes are working. If someone can explain to me where the error is coming from it would be very nice.

Thanks.

This is my `index.js`:

```
 const express = require('express');
 const dotenv = require("dotenv");
 const helmet = require("helmet");
 const morgan = require("morgan");
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 const config = require('./config/config');
 const cors = require('cors');
 const app = express();

 //user routes
 const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoute")
 const authRoute = require("./routes/authRoute")



  //middleware

   app.use(express.json());
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(morgan("common"));

  app.use("/api/user", userRoute);
  app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);







  //connexion to DB 
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');

  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI,(err) => {
 if(!err) { console.log ('MongoDB connection succeded'); }
 else { console.log ('Error in MongoDB connection : ' + JSON.stringufy(err, 
 undefined, 2)); }
 });


 
 app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`Server started at port : 
 ${process.env.PORT}`));
```

my userRoute.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/User');
const router = require("express").Router();



 router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
 res.send('user route');
 //ok 
 })

 //register
 // cannot GET
 router.get("/register", async (req,res)=>{
 const user = await new User({
 username:"john",
 email:"john@gmail.com",
 password:"azerty"
 })
await user.save();
res.send("ok");
 })



 module.exports = router;
```

`authRoute.js`

```
 const express = require('express');
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const User = require('../models/User');
 const router = require("express").Router();



router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
   res.send('user auth');
   //ok
 })



 module.exports = router;
```

Model `user.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username:{
    type:String,
    require: true,
    min: 3,
    max: 20,
    unique:true
},
email:{
    type:String,
    require: true,
    max: 50,
    unique:true
},
password:{
    type:String,
    require: true,
    min: 4,
    unique:true
},
profilPicture:{
    type:String,
    default:""
},
coverPicture:{
    type:String,
    default:""
},
followers:{
    type:Array,
    default:[]
},
followins:{
    type:Array,
    default:[]
},
isAdmin:{
    type:Boolean,
    default:false
},
},
{timestamps:true}
)

 module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);


config.json

{
"development": {
    "PORT": 3000,
    "MONGODB_URI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/socialmedia",
    "JWT_SECRET": "SECRET#123",
    "JWT_EXP": "10m"
},
"production": {
    "PORT": 80,
    "MONGODB_URI": "mongodb://xxxxx/DB_Name",
    "JWT_SECRET": "SECRET#123",
    "JWT_EXP": "2m"
}
 }
```

`config.js`

```
// check env.
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
// fetch env. config
var config = require('./config.json');
var envConfig = config[env];
   // add env. config values to process.env
Object.keys(envConfig).forEach(key => process.env[key] = envConfig[key]);
```

`package.json`

```
{
"name": "server",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "nodemon index.js"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
"body-parser": "^1.20.1",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dotenv": "^16.0.3",
"env": "^0.0.2",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"helmet": "^6.0.0",
"mongoose": "^6.7.1",
"morgan": "^1.10.0",
"nodemon": "^2.0.20"
}
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `/api/user/register`? Because you've added the `/register` handler to the `userRoute.js` file

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the reason why it doesn't work thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `/register` route in your `authRoute.js` file. Modify the contents of the file to this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/User');
const router = require("express").Router();


router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
   res.send('user auth');
   // ok
 })

router.get("/register",(req,res)=>{
   // registering code
 })

module.exports = router;
```

And it should work.

Furthermore, you have a `/register` route in `userRoute.js`. You may need to check if that's intentional - possibly, you've kept code which is meant for `authRoute.js` in `userRoute.js`.

Comment: You are right, i wasn't looking for the good path. Originally my `/register`was at the correct place, in `userRoute.js`, but i was searching the wrong url .. thank you